# Getting new session Id and old session Id before expires

Tags: asp.net, session, cookies

How can i get both old session ID and new session ID before it's expires?
i have a method that checks the session:

```
public void CheckSess()
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Session != null)
    {           
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session.IsNewSession)
        {
            string val1= HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Cookie"];
            if ((null != val1) && (val1.IndexOf("ASP.NET_SessionId") >= 0))
            {                       
                //getting old session and new session  
                var newSession=val1.IndexOf("ASP.NET_SessionId")  //new session
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to do this?  Can't you just make your session timeout longer so that it doesn't expire?

Comment: No, i want to expire somehow, someday..

Comment: But since it was expired, you can use it. why do you need it?

Comment: it is usefull for tracking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of the reasons *why* (which you don't state) to get the currently active, and expiring, session just capture it in the `Session_End` event e.g.

```
void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var oldSessionId = Session.SessionId;        
}
```

Comment: Can we assume that HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID can be the old sessionId?